# how to align count text center in horizontal bar in the Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I  tried with dividing the graph bar value into half part but it's not working!

[Code link](https://codepen.io/bvsbharat/pen/NaGgWN)

[image]

```js
Chart.helpers.each(
            meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
              data = dataset.data[index];
              if (i == 0) {
                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x/1.6, bar._model.y + 4);
              } else {
                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x-25, bar._model.y + 4);
              }
            }),
```

Comment: @GRUNT let me know if u can help me

Comment: are you trying to show the value center of each bar.. like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBuOw.png) ?

Comment: @GRUNT yes  i am !

Answer (score 2):

You can get the center position of each horizontal bar *(inside meta.data loop)* as follows :

```
var barWidth = bar._model.x - bar._model.base;
var centerX = bar._model.base + barWidth / 2;
```

and after getting the position, draw the count text accordingly...

```
Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
   var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
   Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
      var data = dataset.data[index];
      var barWidth = bar._model.x - bar._model.base;
      var centerX = bar._model.base + barWidth / 2;
      if (i == 0) {
         ctx.fillText(data, centerX, bar._model.y + 4);
      } else {
         ctx.fillText(data, centerX, bar._model.y + 4);
      }
   }), this);
}), this);
```

see - [**live demo**](https://codepen.io/gaand/pen/eGpGvz)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very helpful. But, why the `if else`? ```if (i == 0) {
         ctx.fillText(data, centerX, bar._model.y + 4);
      } else {
         ctx.fillText(data, centerX, bar._model.y + 4);
      }``` they are the same